# Django Admin: Need to conditionally display fields

Tags: django, django-admin

What is the best way to conditionally display a field in the admin depending upon the values of other fields?

In particular I'm thinking about the add_form and change_form. Whenever a certain choice is selected I'd like to hide or disable some fields.

I'm thinking that this might require a javascript solution, but am wondering if there is a better (i.e. builtin) way to do this.

Comment: There is no built-in solution to this problem, if you want the fields to display dynamically you will always need a custom javascript/ajax solution!

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case. I am just paranoid about doing things the "Wrong Way".

Answer (score 2):

Bernhard is right. You might be able to hack the admin view and template to conditionally show/not show widgets for a field, but if you want to do it dynamically based on user behaviors in the admin, you'll be using javascript.

It's not so terrible, though. At least the Django admin templates have model- and instance-specific ids to give you granular control over your show/hide behavior.

Comment: I have this same need, and I'm wondering where I would put the javascript code that does this. I.e. in which template?

Answer (score 1):

My answer may sound esoteric - but I suspect the design direction you may be taking could benefit from some reconsideration. When an interface requires that much TLC to resort to AJAX to make for a superior UX I am inclined to not use Admin interface for that.

My personal view of the Admin interface of Django is that it is a great freebie that gives me an instant CRUD view at a basic level. I would refrain from piggy backing on it for those who need a more user friendly interface (even if some of these users are handling admin functions). You will acquire technical debt in trying to do these type of Ajax UI/UX and complex form validations using the Admin interface.

Comment: Actually Bernhard Vallant said my exact thoughts in a much more succinct way. I will upvote his.

Comment: What are some alternatives for building an _admin-panel_ for django, which will be used for managing a REST backend, for an android app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to create your own ModelForm and specify that the admin uses that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form).

Use the _init__() method of the form to selectively display the fields.

I will give it a try and update this answer if it works.

(Actually re-reading the question, it depends. If "values of other fields" is set before the page is loaded, this idea should work. If you want an instant response - click one field and another appears/disappears, yes you will need JavaScript).